# How to decompress .gz file containing multiple files

Tags: java

I want to decompress multiple .gz file by using **java** and all the files(.gz) have multiple files in it:

I've file structure like this:

```
D:\folder\file1.gz
D:\folder\file2.gz
```

And all the gz files are like:

```
file1.gz
abc11.txt
abc12.txt
abc13.txt
abc14.txt
```

```
file2.gz
abc21.txt
abc22.txt
abc23.txt
abc24.txt
```

Comment: What do you mean by "they have multiple files in it"? Is it the gzip of some archive format (tar maybe)?

Comment: I've log files in .gz format from aws elastic load balancer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking doesn't quite make sense.  Do you perhaps actually have a .tar.gz or .tgz file?

Per the Gzip home page (https://www.gzip.org/):

> gzip is a single-file/stream lossless data compression utility, where
>   the resulting compressed file generally has the suffix .gz.

A Gzip file is simply a compressed stream of bytes.  In terms of files, decompressing a .gz file always leads to a single file.  The format provides no provision for breaking the contents of the resulting file into multiple files or assigning names to those files.

There are other file formats that do store multiple files.  Tar is the usual one that is used for this in the same circles where Gzip is used.  Tar files usually have a .tar extension.  But when a Tar is created, it is often immediately compressed with Gzip.  So you often find files in the wild that have the extension .tar.gz.  This means that one or more files were collected into a single Tar file, and then that file was compressed using Gzip.  This scenario is so common, that a single extension, .tgz, is often used as a shortcut for .tar.gz. Also, Tar itself can do Gzip compression, so to create a .tgz file from a directory of files, you can do this:

tar -czf archive.tgz somedirectoryname

If you in fact have a .tar.gz or .tgz file, then the way to decompress and expand that file into multiple files is to first decompress with Gzip and then extract the individual files with Tar.  Tar can do the Gzip decompression itself, so all you need to do to decompress a .tgz file is:

tar -xzf archive.tgz

This will produce whatever files and directory structure was used to create the .tgz file.

If you really have just a .gz file, then I'm not sure what you have, if you're expecting it to expand naturally into multiple files. A .gz file simply isn't able to preserve on its own any notion of multiple files. My guess is that what you have are Gzip compressed individual log files.

Comment: gzip -c file1 file2 > my.gz is a valid command to compress multiple files into a single .gz. Perhaps decompressing a gz created in that way is what they're asking.

Comment: @riffrazor - What that form of the `gzip` command does is, in effect, concatenate the two input files together before compressing them as a single stream.  When you run `gunzip` on `my.gz`, you get a single file named `my` that contains the contents of both the original files, concatenated together.  So this usage is just a convenience to save the user from having to concatenate the files together first, and no notion of multiple files is preserved in the resulting gzip file.

Comment: Thanks @steve. After further reading, it's become clear that this is one of those things that works, but isn't something anyone actually does with gz:)