# How to unzip a .gz file in python and read all the files contained within it into different lists?

Tags: python, gzip

I have a file chrom.txt.gz and within this file I have 30 different text files. I want to open this file with `gzip` and then create a function so that I can read each file and store it in separate lists. The function that I am trying is:

```
def txt_to_list(filename):
  f = open(filename,'r')
  for line in f.readlines():
    lst = line.strip()
    final_list.append(lst)
  return final_list

file1 = txt_to_list('file1.txt')
file2 = .....
```

So, is there anyway to automate this process? so that I don't have to manually call the function 30 times. And I do not understand how to get all the files out after `gzip`. How to do this?

Comment: Are you sure that it's a pure gzip file? According to https://www.gzip.org/ gzip is: `a single-file/stream lossless data compression utility, where the resulting compressed file generally has the suffix .gz`

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54264537/how-to-decompress-gz-file-containing-multiple-files)

Comment: the question is contradictory. A gz file is not an archive it the compressed version of one file.

if you are on unix an the file is called `tst.gz`  could you just type fillowing command on the command line: `file tst.gz` ?